# Is there any way to know purchase made by which iTunes account? - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

My app provides an in-app-purchase non-consumable type. The app has log in facility. Is it possible to make purchase based on logged in user to my app?

I know it sounds awkward. Let me specify the problem.

The device has a already logged in user at iTunes store. At that time, when my app gets install to device for first time, any user can login with credentials to my app. Consider, he made some purchase and log out from the app. Now, another user logged in to the app and can't use facilities available for previous user after in app purchase. But as you know non-consumable product purchase based on iTunes store account (only one non-consumable product can be purchased for each account). I have tried by following way..

1. Store user id to iCloud, but I don't know by which iTunes account that purchase was made. So, I couldn't display proper message "You should log in with different iTunes account to make purchase".
2. In android, with the In-app Billing v3, a `developer payload` string can be sent along with the purchase request. This string is also returned when a query is made for that purchase. So, this can be used to identify the user who made the purchase. Is there anything similar available in iOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of iOS 7, `SKMutablePayment` has an `applicationUsername` property that can be set when a payment is made. And, `SKPaymentQueue` has the `restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername:` method [(link)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername:).

Apple's guidance is to hash your server-side user ID and pass that up on purchase and restore. So, in your case, if iTunes User A purchases the product it will be bound to your server-side user ID for that purchaser. Then, if iTunes User B attempts to restore, restoration will fail, because they would still be passing up the same server-side user ID.

You'll also have to track (on the server) that your server-side user ID has purchased the product. Otherwise, if iTunes User B attempts to restore you'll need to know the difference between they having logged into the device with a different iTunes account and they having never purchased. And of course, you'll also want to prevent the same server-side user from purchasing the product twice, under different iTunes accounts.

Caveats:

- If you already have purchases made in production, this most likely won't work.
- iOS 7+
- The "already purchased" scenario I mentioned above.

Comment: GREAT! Why didn't I know about this before??? A follow-on comment and question. The comment: You have to use SKMutablePayment to access applicationUsername (otherwise, that property is readonly). The question: Consider the following scenario. Suppose Apple ID X and Apple ID Y are both used to make purchases within your app. And you create SKMutablePayments with the same applicationUsername for both Apple ID X and Y (call that applicationUsername, U), then you call restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername with U. This will retrieve purchases made with both Apple ID X and Y?

Comment: @ChrisPrince That's a good point about SKMutablePayment. I've updated my answer. As for your question, I would imagine calling `restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername:` would only return the purchases for the current iTunes user. But, you should prevent the second iTunes user from ever purchasing under the same application user name in the first case. Hence, this is why you need to track the purchases on your own server as well.

Comment: How would that work? How could you prevent the second iTunes user from purchasing under the same application user name?

Comment: Just don't provide any interface to make the purchase.

Comment: Huh? I have no way of detecting which Apple ID a user is using. How can I provide or not provide something if I don't have the information?

Comment: Hence why you need to save the fact that *your* sever-side user has made the purchase. At that point, the iTunes account is irrelevant. You wouldn't provide an interface because the application user has already made the purchase.

Comment: OK-- I see what you're getting at this works in the context of the question the person asked, for non-consumables, but not generally. E.g., it doesn't work for consumables. It doesn't necessarily work for subscriptions (auto-renewing or non-autorenewing).

Comment: @DeepFriedTwinkie thanks for answer. I'm sorry for late acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

if restore purchase is success than purchased made by this account.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];


// Then this is called
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
    NSLog(@"%@",queue );
    NSLog(@"Restored Transactions are once again in Queue for purchasing %@",[queue transactions]);  

    NSMutableArray *purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
        NSLog (@"product id is %@" , productID);
        // here put an if/then statement to write files based on previously purchased items
        // example if ([productID isEqualToString: @"youruniqueproductidentifier]){write files} else { nslog sorry}
    }  
}
```

Comment: Restoration isn't the solution here, because if restoration is successful for a particular iTunes account. Say, A, an app user, made purchase and logged out. Now, B comes and restore. The restoration will be successful because iTunes account isn't changed yet. But B hasn't purchased the product, yet he enjoy the facility.

Comment: In-app purchase is working on itunes account so we can't prevent B to enjoy facility. That's not possible.

Comment: Yes you are right. But, that is the requirement. Lets see what other people say.