# In-App Purchase Auto renewal purchase by Username

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app

I'm implementing Auto-Renewal In app Purchase.I have a few questions Please clarify.
Really appreciate your help.

1.user1 make purchase a plan which is 30 days plan with device1 with his iTunes account and User 2 makes purchase another plan which is 60 days plan with device 2 with his iTunes account, what happens if user1 logged into device2 but device2 still have user2 iTunes account.if i restore purchase or receipt validation in device 2 i'll get User 2 purchase as auto-renewals will work with iTunes Account.

how we can make sure that user1 should get 30 days plan only not 60 days plan.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please clarify "what happens if user1 logged into device2 but device2 still have user2 iTunes account." Is user 1 entering the device's passcode but not logging out of user 2's itunes account? Does your app have a separate server based username that the user's login with?

Comment: Yes My app has login

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your user's login name with the purchase and restore requests to allow Apple to improve fraud detection, but that will not actually prevent the purchase or restoration (whether fraudulent or just not what you intended).

(And thus with hindsight not an answer but leaving this here for reference - see comments.)

For example [restoreCompletedTransactions(withApplicationUsername:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1505992-restorecompletedtransactions)

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29280858/2466193) for more details.

And [this Apple Developer forum conversation](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12850) for why it will not actually prevent purchase/restore by the 'wrong' user.

Comment: Thank you Ali Beadle, for your answer.Please Check Chris prince comments in abpve link

 Consider the following scenario. Suppose Apple ID X and Apple ID Y are both used to make purchases within your app. And you create SKMutablePayments with the same applicationUsername for both Apple ID X and Y (call that applicationUsername, U), then you call restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername with U. This will retrieve purchases made with both Apple ID X and Y?

Comment: I see - yes you are correct, this is for fraud prevention by Apple and will still return all transactions, even if the usernames do not match. I accept that is not the answer to your problem but will edit it to clarify and leave it for reference.